# Get all posts by a user's tags?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

By user's tags I mean users can follow tags. I have a model called `Tagfollow`
Tagfollow

```
class Tagfollow extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

In addition to this I have User, Tag and Post models with following relations between them.

Post

```
user() belongsTo App\User 
tags() belongsToMany App\Tag
```

User

```
posts() hasMany App\Post
tagfollow() hasMany App\Tagfollow
```

Tag

```
posts() belongsToMany App\Post
```

I'm not fully sure if relation are correct.

I want to get ids of all tags a users is following and then get all posts form each of those tags.

here's the code i have so far.

```
    $user = Auth::user();
    $tag_ids= $user->tagfollow()->pluck('tag_id')->toArray();
    $tags=Tag::whereIn('id', $tag_ids)->get();
    $post_ids=[];
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $post_ids = array_merge($post_ids, $tag->posts()->pluck('post_id')->toArray());
    }
    $posts =Post::whereIn('user_id', $user_ids)->whereIn('id', $post_ids)->orderby('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
```

$user_ids is list of auth user's following's user ids.

this code sort of works, it only gets posts for one of the whereIn clause. there has to be a better way of doing this with Eloquent, Like just getting posts from users tags instead of getting tag id and then looping through each tag.

Comment: are you using  pivot table  ? also you can check link : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I have a user and a tag table. tag table has tag name and tag_id. For tag following i have another table, Tagfollow table stores users tag following so it has id tag_id and user_id.

Comment: The `tagfollow() hasMany App\Tagfollow` relation should be a many-to-many.

Comment: @HaseebAhmed you can use pivot table .. it will be many to many relation ship...

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't it already many-to-many relation. Anyway i don't have any issues with user following tags and getting posts based on user tag followings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` on the relationship query

```php
// Get all tags id followed by user

$tagsId = $user->tagFollow()->pluck('tag_id')->toArray();

// Get all posts with corrensponding tag

$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tagsId) {
  $query->whereIn('tags.id', $tagsId);
})->get()
```

Comment: i'm getting this error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` = 1 and `posts`.`user_id` is not null and exists (select * from `tags` inner join `post_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `post_tag`.`tag_id` where `posts`.`id` = `post_tag`.`post_id` and `id` in (19, 24, 23, 18)))

Comment: Also, $posts = $user->posts() doesn't that mean its only getting auth user's posts.

Comment: Oh yeah, right. You should use `whereIn('tags.id', $tagsId);`. I edit my answer for both problems

Comment: it works.but where do i put the second whereIn.  whereIn('user_id', $user_ids)

Comment: solved it, had to use orWhereIn('user_id', $user_ids)